# Are falling coconuts more dangerous than sharks?

Tags: sharks

I was fortuitously reading about sharks in the Mediterranean Sea on a small Italian online news site.
As a side note the article claims that an average of seven people are injured or killed (not clear) by sharks, yearly and worldwide - while dozens of peoples are victims of coconuts.
I suppose falling coconuts.

[ABC News](https://abcnews.go.com/Technology/story?id=97993&page=1) makes a similar claim:

> Burgess pointed to recent data that suggested people were 15 times more likely to be killed by falling coconuts than by a shark.

Is this true, or at least are coconuts accidents a thing?

Comment: Is this threat per coconut/shark, or threat per person? Are we asking whether walking under a coconut tree is more dangerous than swimming with sharks, or are we just asking which one a randomly selected person is more likely to die from?

Comment: @user253751: I think the claims makes it clear it is latter.

Comment: Basically " are there more deaths by sharks attack or by falling nurs?".

Comment: Either, the beachgoers are under trees then sharks will have a hard time getting them, or they are in the water, then sharks will still have a hard time because they need open water to breathe. Wading/swimming persons will not be hit by a nut. It would be nice to have the statistics the claim is based on.

Comment: There is actually a [Snopes article](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/coconuts-kill-more-sharks/) on this matter, concluding, amazingly enough, that there's just not enough research on lethal coconuts.

Also, I was shocked - shocked! - to learn that there is a Wikipedia article "[Death by coconut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_by_coconut)"...

Comment: @P_S I see why you have just commented. But it serves as quite an answer. Thx.